# C# Async Multiple Web Requests to DataTable - Work appears to stop for unknown reasons

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, async-await, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am developing a single form app that, on button press, makes a simple inventory database API query, and checks each returned ItemID# for a corresponding image which may or may not exist at a URL formed from the ID#. I am currently doing this by sending HttpWebRequest.Method = "HEAD" requests for each URL, returning true unless the catch block is triggered.

The database query may return 50 - 150 part numbers, and sending HEAD requests to each one individually in this way takes about 5 minutes and this is not productive.

I am trying to multi-task this process using async and await. When I click the button, it works fine, asynchronously loading rows into my DataGridView one by one, at a rate of about 2/second (which isnt bad, but I would still like to speed this up if possible).

HOWEVER: After finding 2 successful URL responses, it stops loading rows and appears to just give up, for reasons unknown to me??? And the syncContext block which re-enables the UI is never executed, because the work is never completed. Can anyone see what might be causing this to happen?

I have been working loosely based off this doc:

"How to: Make Multiple Web Requests in Parallel by Using async and await (C#)"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674880.aspx

```
namespace ImageTableTest
{
public partial class ImageTableTestForm : Form
{
    //P21 Authentication Variables
    private static Token P21token = null;
    private static RestClientSecurity rcs;

    //Create Tables and bindingSource
    DataTable itemDataIMG = new DataTable();
    DataTable itemDataNOIMG = new DataTable();
    DataTable itemDataComplete = new DataTable();
    BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();

    private readonly SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext;


    public ImageTableTestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Create syncContexct on UI thread for updating UI
        synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        //authenticate database API function
        authenticateP21();     

        //Designing DataTables
        itemDataIMG.Columns.Add("MPN#", typeof(string));
        itemDataIMG.Columns.Add("IMG", typeof(bool));
        itemDataIMG.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;

        itemDataNOIMG.Columns.Add("MPN#", typeof(string));
        itemDataNOIMG.Columns.Add("IMG", typeof(bool));
        itemDataNOIMG.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;

        itemDataComplete.Columns.Add("MPN#", typeof(string));
        itemDataComplete.Columns.Add("IMG", typeof(bool));
        itemDataComplete.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true; 

        //bind to DataGridView itemView
        bindingSource.DataSource = itemDataComplete;          
        itemView.DataSource = bindingSource;
        itemView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    }



    private async void testBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //When button is clicked, disable UI and
        //start background work:
        testBtn.Enabled = false;
        loadSpinner.Visible = true;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            getItemView();
        });
    }


    private async void getItemView()
    {
        try
        {
            //This executes the query and returns an array of Part objects:
            PartResourceClient prc = new PartResourceClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["P21.BaseURI"], rcs);
            prc.QueryFilter("add_to_ebay eq 'Y'");
            Part[] pResults = prc.Resource.GetParts();              

            int numParts = pResults.Length;                
            Task<bool>[] taskArray = new Task<bool>[numParts];
            bool[] IMGboolArray = new bool[numParts];

            //For each part, create CheckImageURL task and add to task Array
            //Then Await execution
            for (int i = 0; i < numParts; i++)
            {
                taskArray[i] = CheckImageURL(pResults[i].ItemId);
                IMGboolArray[i] = await taskArray[i];
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }

        //When all Tasks finish, remove loadSpinner, re-enable UI
        //(This never executes for unknown reasons.)
        synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
        {              
            loadSpinner.Visible = false;
            testBtn.Enabled = true;
        }), null);

        MessageBox.Show("<DONE>");
    }


    async Task<bool> CheckImageURL(string MPN)
    {
        //Here I am forming and executing the web HEAD request,
        //If there is there is a 'NOT FOUND' response it goes to 'catch' block:
        string URL = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/www.crosscreektractor.com/ebay-images/" + MPN + "_e.png";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        try
        {
            await request.GetResponseAsync();
            synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
            {
                addDataRows(MPN, true);
            }), null);

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
            {
                addDataRows(MPN, false);
            }), null);

            return false;
        }
    }

    private void addDataRows(string MPN, bool IMG)
    {
        //Add data to respective table:
        if (IMG)
        {
            itemDataIMG.Rows.Add(MPN, IMG);
        }
        else
        {
            itemDataNOIMG.Rows.Add(MPN, IMG);
        }

        //Here I am sorting the IMG and NOIMG tables,
        //then merging them into the Complete table which
        //The DataGridView is bound to, so that IMG entries are on top:
        itemDataIMG.DefaultView.Sort = ("MPN# DESC");
        itemDataNOIMG.DefaultView.Sort = ("MPN# DESC");

        itemDataComplete.Clear();
        itemDataComplete.Merge(itemDataIMG);
        itemDataComplete.Merge(itemDataNOIMG);
        itemView.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: You are missed in TAP and async/await. It is wrong approach implementing and using task-based asynchronous pattern.

Comment: Hamlet, is that what is causing it to stall, or would it just be lower overhead if done differently? Maybe you could provide documentation or tell me which lines look messed up?

Comment: google by keywords TAP, async/await, task-based asynchronous pattern.

Comment: That is how I have gotten this far, and it seems to be working fine except it hangs after finding, specifically, 2 successful URLs. I have read many things about TAP, async & await. This is the implementation described in the microsoft guide I sited. If you see something that I coded wrong, please inform me.

Comment: In microsoft guide can't be things like this `await request.GetResponseAsync();
            synchronizationContext.Post(`. There is a paradigm `await all the way`. You should follow that paradigm. Your `getItemView` should return `Task` and you should await to that `Task` in your handler.

Comment: Your `IMGboolArray` assigned but not used. What is the meaning of that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice on my TAP patterns, definitely learning a lot about TAP.

The solution to my problem was the HttpWebRequest connection limit. On the successful requests it does not then auto-close the connection, and you must do so by grabbing the WebResponse and closing it (only needed on the successful connections):

```
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
{do stuff}
response.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `getItemView()` method to be `Task` returning, like so:

```
private async Task getItemView()
```

Then instead of using `Task.Run` simply `await` this call in the click event handler like so:

```
await getItemView();
```

Comment: It still just stops adding rows after CheckImageURL() returns true twice for some reason.

Comment: Also when I do it this way, the UI freezes up as the query is being completed, so I think I will continue using await Task.Run ()